# software center install button does't work

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, ubuntu-mate, edubuntu, linux-headers

My software center install botton does't work. I tried changing the server but that didn't work . My Ubuntu version is 16.04.

Comment: Open Updates and install them. Then you should be able to use Ubuntu Software.

Comment: What are you trying to install and what error are you getting ? If you are not getting an error , try the command line `sudo apt update && sudo apt install your_package`

Comment: I did but it's not worked .i'm trying to install wine  @bodhi.zazen

Comment: Open a terminal and enter `sudo apt update && sudo apt install wine` and post any errors you get.

Comment: Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:33963 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:33963:
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:33963:
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:33963:
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:33963 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: C

Comment: @RezaQasemi Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/959766/edit) 
 your question and add the full error message in a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: I solved it. It was proxy error . I changed proxy to none in setting and it worked. tank u@dessert